# Big-Oh and theta notation of a specific function... Running time

Tags: performance, big-o

If evaluating f(n) is theta(n)

```
i = 1;
sum = 0;
while (i <= n)
       do if (f(i) > k)
            then sum += f(i);
          i = 2*i;
```

Would the running time of this be O(n^3) because of the n times the functions are possibly being called or would it be O(n)? Or is it something in terms of theta since that's the information we know? I am very lost on this...

Comment: The complexity is O(N*LogN).

Comment: Computing f(i) has complexity O(n) or O(i)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **i** variable doubles each time => will reach **n** in **Log2(n)** time.
The evaluation of f will be done Log2(n) times => the function time complexity is **O(N x LogN)**.

In fact, if computing f(i) has complexity O(i), then the time complexity is:

```
1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^(Log2(n)) = n (there are Log2(n) steps) => O(n)
```